# Wordpress WooCommerce Change spacing of items in "Featured Products" Slider

Tags: css, wordpress, slider, woocommerce, spacing

I added some borders to the divs surrounding each product in the slider, and in doing that changed the total width of the wrapper they are in.

I am looking to shrink the spacing between each item in the slider, so the all fit in the 940px div around them., and don't get cut off on the right side. Adjusting the margin-right property of each item isn't having an effect.

Any ideas? Thanks!

http://montagewestport.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following:

```
.slider .product_item {
  margin: 0 30px 30px 0px !important;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 100px !important;
}
```